# DRY in UJS in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, dry, ujs

I want to work DRYingly in the UJS and not repeat pieces of javascript

I also want to run specific js code depending on variables I get from the controller

so for example this could be the type of code in a ujs response

```
<% if !flash[:error].blank? %>
alert("there is an error! - <%= flash[:error] %>");
<% else %>
alert("nothing to see here, move along now.. <%= flash[:success] %>");
<% end %>
```

so I'd like to fire this code in a few ujs responses, but I don't know where to place it. Helper files are for html..

Where can I place such js/erb hybrid code so it can be reuseable - so I can call it from any .js.erb file?

Comment: Basically, you want to use .js.erb files like templates or partials?

Comment: yeah thats what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render a partial from within your js.erb using the following syntax:

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/alerts" %>
```

Just put your code above into a partial in the appropriate directory. In my above example, the file would be called _alerts.js.erb and you'd put the partial in a directory I called shared (which would be in your views directory), but you can choose whatever directory you deem appropriate.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, since this will append the js code in the partial in that selector. I want to js code to execute

Comment: Whoops - sorry about that. I've edited the code - does it work now?